# Gatling error : Failed to build request: No attribute named 'jwtoken' is defined

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have this error when running my script in scala: "Failed to build request: No attribute named 'jwtoken' is defined " , i extract the value of jwtoken then i put it in a variable, then i want to read it in an other request, i have put 2 objects because i want run two scenario's :

```
class PPT_GET extends Simulation
  {  val httpProtocol = http
.baseUrl("") // Here is the root for all relative URLs
  
    val acteurscsv = csv("./src/test/resources/Data/ksp-acteurs.csv").circular
    val jwt = "123"
  

       object TokenGen {
     val tokenGen = exec(http("access_token")
       .post("https://URL1/token")
       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
       .formParam("grant_type", value = "client_credentials") 
       .formParam("client_id", value = "PRTAPIPPD")
       .formParam("client_secret", value = "xxxxxx")
       .check(status is 200, jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("atoken")))
    
       .exec(http("jwt_token")
         .get("https://bsc-ppd.web.bpifrance.fr/mga/sps/apiauthsvc/policy/AT4JWT")
         .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${atoken}")
         .header("CorrelationID", "someID")
         .header("UsercallerSecret", "user1")
         .header("UsercallerID", "X1")
         .header("Accept", "application/json")
         .check(status is 200, jsonPath("$.JWTFull").saveAs("jwtoken")))     //here i extract the variable jwtoken
             }

    object Acteurs {

      val acteurs =
        pause(80)
          .feed(acteurscsv)
          .exec(http("ksp-acteurs")
            .get("https://URL1/ksp-acteurs/${ACTCODE}") 
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${jwtoken}" )    // here where i have the erreor
            .check(status is 200))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have put 2 objects because i want run two scenario's

This is not how things work. A scenario is a virtual user journey and data is saved in each virtual user's memory space called `Session`.

So you can't save data with a check in one scenario and expect to find it in another one, because those scenarios would be executed by different virtual users.

You have to chain your requests in the same scenario, eg:

```scala
val scn = scenario("foo").exec(TokenGen.tokenGen, Acteurs.acteurs)
```

Then, if your goal is to generate one single token for your test, you can use a global reference and sequential scenarios:

```scala
var token: String = null

val generateToken = scenario("loadToken")
  .exec(TokenGen.tokenGen)
  .exec { session =>
  token = session("jwtoken").as[String]
  session
  }


    object Acteurs {

      val acteurs =
          feed(acteurscsv)
          .exec(http("ksp-acteurs")
            .get("https://URL1/ksp-acteurs/${ACTCODE}") 
            .header("Authorization", _ => s"Bearer $token" )
            .check(status is 200))
    }

setUp(
  generateToken.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
    .andThen(
      scenario("acteurs").exec(Acteurs.acteurs).inject(???)
    )
)
```

Comment: Think you stéphane, i will put it in one object, but my need is want generate the token 1 time every 10 minutes (because i won't send  token's requests every time), have you an idea to do it ?